# it happen vs it happens

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

The last sentence in the context contains "you have seen it happen", why not "...it happens"?

> Exercise boosts mood and sunlight seems to help beat back the winter blues. So slap on some sunblock and go! If you need more convincing, remember this: staying in shape during the winter gets you physically ready for springtime activities (and wardrobes). If you’re into sports, you’ve **seen it happen**.

Answer (score 2):

The verb in  the object complement is the bare infinitive.

> I heard her <sup>object</sup> **sing**. <sup>complement</sup>
>
> I saw him <sup>object</sup> **run**. <sup>complement</sup>
>
> You have seen it <sup>object</sup> **happen**.<sup>complement</sup>
>
> When we put the video in super slow-motion, we can see the hummingbird's wings **beat**.

The objects are not in nominative case but objective case (her, him).

This construction is not to be confused with a relative clause:

You have seen that it happens.

Comment: Well, as I've understood, in this phrase "You have seen it happen"  we have here "complex object" construction and it expresses completed action - "...it happen". And if we say "You have seen that it happens" - it's present simple tense and "the action" may be repeated once in a while or often ...Am I on the right track? Thanks!